# Setting type for React Typescript component attribute

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts

I keep getting `ts error #2741 (Property 'datasets' is missing in type)`. [image: See img below]

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to set type for the `data` attribute of the `<Bar />` component. I've tried `data: string[]` inline and so many other variations.

```js
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import './Chart.css';

export default function Chart() {
  return (
    <div className="data">
      Chart
      <Bar
        data={{
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange']
        }}
        height={400}
        width={400}
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`datasets` is a required property of the `data` type. In your example you only provided the `labels` property, thus typescript is throwing that error.

A valid data object should look like this:

```js
data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [20, 10],
    }],
    labels: ['a', 'b']
}
```

From chartjs docs:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html

Comment: I wish that got me somewhere but I'm getting even more errors now.

```Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ChartData<"bar", number[], unknown>'.ts(2322)```

```Cannot find name 'datasets'.ts(2304)```
```Cannot find name 'data'.ts(2304)```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the data you are giving your **Bar** component data the  should look something like this as suggested from the [Chart JS Docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html)

```
data: {
 datasets: [{
   data: [20, 10],
 }],
 labels: ['a', 'b']
}
```

*Note: When the data is an array of numbers, values from labels array at the same index are used for the index axis (x for vertical, y for horizontal charts).*